# mysql union fails for no obvious reason

Tags: mysql

this is my query:

```
SELECT m_title `title` from members UNION select n_title `title` FROM news
```

this sql query fails for no obvious reason although the next query succeeded:

```
SELECT id from members UNION select n_id `title` FROM news
```

what could be the problem?

**members:**

```
id  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT    Change      Drop   More 
 2  member_id   int(150)            No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 3  m_title varchar(200)    utf8_unicode_ci     Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
 4  txtshortdetails text    utf8_unicode_ci     No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 5  txtfulldetails  text    utf8_unicode_ci     No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 6  video_src   varchar(200)    utf8_unicode_ci     No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 7  m_order int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 8  m_cat   int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 9  m_date  datetime            No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 10 m_change_date   date            No  None          Change      Drop   More
```

**news:**

```
n_id    int(10)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT    Change      Drop   More 
 2  n_title varchar(200)    utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
 3  n_details   text    utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
 4  n_pic   varchar(200)    utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
 5  n_order int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 6  n_date  date            Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More
```

Comment: Is there a column `m_title` in `members`?

Comment: yes, all column names are right

Comment: Try looking at the [`Collate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//charset-collate.html) keyword.

Answer (score 0):

#### Just a try, giving `AS` keyword:

Correct me if I am wrong.

```
SELECT `m_title` AS `title` FROM `members`
UNION
SELECT `n_title` AS `title` FROM `news`
```

And make sure that the columns `m_title` and `n_title` exists in the respective tables.

Comment: I checked this query with more than one db's.. the same error:
#1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

Comment: I asked you for something!

Comment: what is this "Database schema dump"?

Comment: The database queries to create them.

Comment: I modified the question, and i hope this answers you

Comment: @ahmed Good but, can you make an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? Sorry for straining you so much!

Comment: Google your error message. You've got a mismatch of collation, but it could be in a number of places. Google will give you tons of links to explore the issue

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your help.
the problem was in the different collations of the 2 columns.
the first has: "utf8_general_ci"
and the second has: "utf8_unicode_ci"
I made them the same

Comment: Or you could have set the collation when comparing/unioning them rather than changing the column, as I suggested in the comments on your question...